# Example value for a nautilus (file manager) connect to service custom location

Tags: command-line, nautilus

I am looking for an example for a [nautilus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus_%28file_manager%29) (file manager) connect to service custom location.

```
$ nautilus
```

Activate connection editor:

```
File>Connect To Server...>
```

I am looking for an example or two for "Location" in the pop up:

```
Service Type: [Custom Location]
Location: [???]
[x] Add bookmark
Bookmark name: [xyz]
<Connect>
```

Service Type values are:

- SSH
  -FTP (with login)
- Public FTP
- Windows Share
- WebDAV (HTTP)
- Secure WebDAV (HTTPS)
- Custom Location

Comment: This isn't clear enough for me to understand.

Comment: @Tshepang: I have a clue as to what the possible meaning is for all of the Service Type values except "Custom Location" so, I am looking for an example.

Answer (score 2):

From the [nautilus user guide](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/stable/nautilus-server-connect.html.en):

> If the server information is provided
>   in the form of a URI, or you require a
>   specialized connection, choose Custom
>   Location as the service type.

I have no idea what that actually entails. I tried smb and ftp servers and was told I must enter a name for the server. Maybe someone else knows more.